# Is it possible to use the same user for two GitLab runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on three git repositories, one of these repositories is 'Tool_repository'.

I created a Gitlab pipeline for the "Tool_repository", and this pipeline is split in several steps, one of these steps needs (it's mandatory) to be executed as an user.
For each pipeline, a directory is created with the id corresponding to the build which is checked, and as only one pipeline is running there is no issue, but when I launch several jobs (ie several pipelines are created): the first directory is created as my user, but the second is created as "nfsnobody".

Here is my config.toml file for runners: [config.toml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfTix.png)

To install gitlab-runner I made these steps:

`sudo gitlab-runner install --working-directory /PATH/TO/WORKING/DIR --user myUser`

`sudo service gitlab-runner restart`

Is it possible to run several pipelines simultaneously as my user ? Is there something to add to runner configuration file ?

Thank you.

I try to uninstall, re-install several times gitlab-runner.